# How to enabled JQuery Intelisence in VisualStudio 2008

Tags: jquery, visual-studio-2008

I use windows 8 (64bit), Visual Studio 2008 SP1 (version 9.0.30729.1)
I 've already installed hotfix KB958502. The following link:
[http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/KB958502/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=1736][1]

I put jquery-20.0.0-vsdoc.js and jquery-2.0.0.min.js in the same folder (which is named "js") in my application.

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.0.0.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("p").css("color", "red");
    });
</script>
```

When I type: $("p"). the intelisence doesn't work.
What should I do?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I 've solved it.
I got this warning from visual studio "Error updating JScript IntelliSense.."

After googling, I found out that I have to use "jquery-2.0.0.js" instead of "jquery-2.0.0.min.js"

There are some several reference. Here is the links:
[Change the path of js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/677440/how-to-fix-this-jquery-intellisense-in-visual-studio-2008-problem)

[Use jquery-2.0.0.js instead of jquery-2.0.0.min.js](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/error-updating-jscript-intellisense-jquery-1-4-1-min-js-object-doesn-t-support-this-property-or-method)