# How to use intellisense.js file that came with jQuery NuGet package 1.8.0 instead of vsdoc.js?

Tags: jquery, visual-studio, intellisense, visual-studio-2012

I just found that the lastest version (1.8.0) of jQuery NuGet package include the new type of vsdoc file that I cannot find any documentation. The intellisense file just only include xml comment-based document of jQuery library. I don't sure how to use this file.

[image: intellisense file]

Do you have any idea or document about this? I use VS2012 for this project.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/59766/how-do-you-get-javascript-jquery-intellisense-working-in-vs-2008 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218578/visual-studio-jscript-intellisense-error-with-jquery-1-2-6.

Comment: I know that and I already mention about that. I have use vsdoc file since Microsoft release it.

Comment: useful video http://www.asp.net/visual-studio/overview/2013/visual-studio-2013-web-editor-features-javascript

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In JavaScript file, the JavaScript language service provides IntelliSense features for third-party JavaScript libraries that are added to a project. For most libraries, statement completion is provided automatically by the language service. The following illustration shows an example of statement completion:

[image]

In Visual Studio 2012, Visual Studio will automatically find ".intellisense.js" file and use it like old vsdoc file without writing real JavaScript structure.

[image]

For additional information, please look at the following link.

[Extending JavaScript IntelliSense](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh874692.aspx)

Comment: Is it is passoible to place *.intellisence.js in different directory than library?

Comment: @Zeshan no, it needs to be in the same directory. Also it is `*.intellisense.js` not `*.intellisence.js`

Answer (score 14):

you don't need to do anything. you just need to install or update jquery package from nuget by using

```
Install-Package jQuery
```

or

```
Update-Package jQuery
```

and then the intellisense and documentation is available everywhere.

you don't need vsdoc anymore because the new file jquery-1.8.0.intellisense is more organized.

There is also a great video by Scott Hanselman at the following url which shows the new features of JavaScript editor in visual studio 2012 http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/videos/visual-studio-2012-javascript-editor

Comment: "Install-Package jQuery" Worked For Me Perfectly

Comment: "you don't need vsdoc anymore" - That's interesting, I'm trying to find evidence in the form of something official or an explanation if this is true - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39324160/are-vsdoc-javascript-files-still-used-in-visual-studio-2015-or-are-they-superced