# Difference between these jQuery intellisense files?

Tags: jquery, nuget, intellisense

What is the difference (for Visual Studio) between these two types of jQuery intellisense files?

- jquery-1.11.1.intellisense.js
- jquery-1.11.1-vsdoc.js

I noticed in nuget, when you want to get jQuery package, it downloads *.intellisense.js file, but when you want to get jQuery UI package (with jQuery included), it downloads *-vsdoc.js

Any idea why and whats the difference?

Thanks.

Comment: Why you dont try to search?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12010106/how-to-use-intellisense-js-file-that-came-with-jquery-nuget-package-1-8-0-instea

Comment: I have read through this post, my question is different.
First we dont use nuget, second - I am asking about the difference between these files.

Comment: Im not sure, and mb im wrong, but vsdoc are deprecated, and now should to use intellisense.