# Intellisense missing for ajax with jQuery in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, visual-studio

### I'm new in ASP.NET, I'm making a website and I need ajax to do something. But when I try to call ajax in jQuery, it doesn't appear after `$.` sign. I have downloaded latest version jQuery. I'm using Visual Studio 2010.

I took a picture for my problem. I tried some soluntion above but ajax still not work.[The picture for my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnRfr.png)

Comment: So you mean to say you're not getting intellisense?

Comment: The intellisense in VS 2010 for Javascript is not great. If you're expecting it to behave as well as it does when you're writing C# code then that's not going to happen. If you simply call `$.ajax(...);` what happens?

Comment: And to think, there were people (like me) who actually coded stuff without Intellisense/code completion....

Comment: https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/jquery-1-4-1-intellisense-with-visual-studio

Comment: Thank you for helping i'll try it

Comment: Thank you everyone. This is amazing forum for sharing code and experience. This forum helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

This example can be used to get you started.
This can be your view:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index28</title>
    @*the next line should point to your jquery*@
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#create").click(function () {
                var MyModel = {
                    ArticleName: $("#articleName").val(),
                    CountField: $("#countField").val(),
                    PriceField: $("#priceField").val()
                }
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/Home/GoIntoMethod',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: MyModel,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (result) {
                        $("#targetName").val(result.targetName);
                        $("#targetCount").val(result.targetCount);
                        $("#targetPrice").val(result.targetPrice);
                    },
                    error: function (data, status, error) {
                        //alert("error");
                    }
                });
            })
        })
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        @*you can make these field using html helper*@
        <input type="text" id="targetName" />
        <input type="text" id="targetCount" />
        <input type="text" id="targetPrice" />
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <input id='create' type="submit" value="Save" />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GoIntoMethod() 
    {
        //put a breakpoint here to see you can do whatever you want with the fields
        return Json(new
        {
            targetName = "aName",
            targetCount = "4",
            targetPrice = "2.37"
        }
         , @"application/json");
    }

    public ActionResult Index28(int? id)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: I think my problem is i put a batch of javascript code below </html>. But i'll try your example. Thanks

Comment: @binhnguyen You can use this cdn for jquery  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>

Comment: @binhnguyen I am getting intellisence.  I never use it in javascript/jquery, so you don't really need it.  But to research it, you can view this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12010106/how-to-use-intellisense-js-file-that-came-with-jquery-nuget-package-1-8-0-instea

Comment: Thank you so much for give me information about jquery intellisense. That is the key for my solution. Wish you a good day :)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for helping me. I found the solution for my problem. I search on google for jquery older version (1.8.0) and i copy all code in that jquery then paste it in my jquery file. After do that i can call ajax.[My picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yet9k.png)